# Спарсить 1 id с сайта. Головоломка

Tags: php, синтаксический-анализ

Всем доброго вечера

```
$ch = curl_init('http://vk.com/id123456789');
$html=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// в переменной $html у нас теперь страничка

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$a = $doc->getElementById('profile_time_lv'); // выдергиваем из страницы определенный id
print_r($a);
echo "--"; // супер строка
```

Прочитал много про `cUrl`, и многое уже попробовал. Не врубаюсь как получить `html` содержание определенного элемента на сайте по его `id`. Можете посоветовать, как правильно написать?

p.s. пример привел случайно, т.к. он простой. Думал в переменной будет:

```
$a = "заходила вчера в 14:57</b> Ирина Кутарёва</h1>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читайте [документацию](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). getElementById возвращает объект типа DOMElement. Его содержимое можно получить ис свойства nodeValue.

```
print($a->nodeValue);
```

Comment: переписал. все равно не работает. пустое место там, где должно быть значение у элемента

    $ch = curl_init('http://vk.com/id123456789');
    $html=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $a = $doc->getElementById('profile_time_lv'); // выдергиваем из     страницы определенный id
    print($a->nodeValue);
    echo "--"; // супер строка

Comment: Сохраните скачанную страницу на диск и откройте любимым редактором. Посмотрите внимательно. Часто браузеры показывают не совсем тот исходный код, который на самом деле, а "немножко исправленный" - теги к примеру позакрывает. А некоторые сайты, видя, что к ним не браузером зашли, могут отдать совсем другую страницу.

Comment: для vk вроде как апи существует, а так - там это время заполняется через js. видимо.

Comment: Откройте нужный урл в режиме Инкогнито в хроме(например) и гляньте исходник, там нет `profile_time_lv`